# Run-time error '5': Invalid porcedure call or argument

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have 2 pivot tables in my workbook and I have the following code to dynamically change the data source and refresh the pivot tables. The code runs fine as it loops through the first `For Each pt` loop and the first Pivot Table is refreshed. However, when it is looped for the second Pivot Table, the code crashes at `pt.ChangePitvotCache` with an error:

> Run-time error = '5': invalid procedure call or argument"

Does anyone able to help on why this doesn't work as soon as I have more than 1 Pivot-Table in the code?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim newRange As String 

Set DataSource = DataSht.Range("A1", DataSht.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))

newRange = DataSht.Name & "!" & DataSource.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=newRange)

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        pt.ChangePivotCache pvtCache
        pt.RefreshTable
    Next pt
Next ws
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "Reset" the `pvtCache` after you set it to the first `PivotTable`.

So you need to `Set` the `pvtCache` and "Reset" it inside the `For Each pt In ws.PivotTables` loop.

Try the code below:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=newRange)
        pt.ChangePivotCache pvtCache
        pt.RefreshTable
        Set pvtCache = Nothing
    Next pt
Next ws
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, your suggestion worked but only in the case where the second PT doesn't share a PivotCache with the first. I have now added a cloned PT on a new sheet and now the code gives that error on the first For Each pt In ws.PivotTables loop...

Comment: Actually it works also for that case as well, did u remove the set pvtCache before the loop ?

Comment: I've removed the pvtCache before the loop and still getting the same error. I've managed to narrowed the problem down a bit, it seems like the issue arises only when there is a slicer connected to the cloned pivottables

Comment: All of your `PivotTable`s in all worksheets share the same `PivotCache` ?

Comment: Yes, its just 2 tables sharing the same cache. I've just managed to find a way around the problem. I've added a line of code to make the source data a table every time it is refreshed and linked the Pivot Tables to the table name so I don't need to change the PivotCache now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Got around having to change the PivotCache each time the dataset is generated by converting the data source to a table and changing the source of the pivot tables to the table name.

```
Activesheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(1, "A").End(xlDown), Cells(1, "A").End(xlToRight)), , xlYes).Name = "DataTable"
```